# Need help with symbolic integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I have

```
f[x_] := g[x]/g'[x] 
FullSimplify[Integrate[f[x], x]]
```

I'm trying to get `F[x]` in terms of `g[x]`, but evaluating the above gives the random expression below as output

> ```
> 1/4 (x^2 + 2 Log[x])
> ```

How would I get `F[x]` based on  `g[x]` to be returned?

Comment: What's the definition of `g`?

Comment: @JohnDoty Nothing, that's all I have input. I'm trying to make it generic so I didn't make g(x) anything I just want it to base it in terms of g(x). That's why I have no idea where it's getting the output from.

Comment: It's possible you defined one of those functions earlier and forgot.  To clear any such definitions, try quitting the kernel and re-evaluating that cell.  You should get $\int \frac{g(x)}{g'(x)} \, dx$  (that's what I get).

Comment: Is it possible that you are looking for `Integrate[g'[x]/g[x], x] (*Log[g[x]]*)`?

Comment: @theorist So I quit the kernel and it doesn't give the random output anymore and I get what you put in. But I'm trying to make it so that there's no integral in the answer. Is Mathematica able to do that?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Nah I'm trying to integrate the inverse of that.  I'm trying to get the function that's derivative is inverse of the derivative of 'Log[g[x]]'

Comment: The integral has no closed-form solution.

Comment: Apparently, `g` is defined as `g[x_] := Log[x]`...